# Symfony2 @UniqueEntity constraint on 2 foreign keys not working

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
@UniqueEntity({"store_id","user_id"})
```

**php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force**

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata.

I tried to delete and create the table again, there is no unique key created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

@UniqueEntity(fields={"store_id","user_id"})
```

Bear in mind the validator has nothing to do with the underlying database schema, it just validates the current state of the object. If you want to create a custom unique index consult the [@UniqueConstraint annotation in doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint):

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"store_id", "user_id"})})
 */
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```